# Using Select Value to Change Objects Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have three objects `foo`,`bar`, and `baz` with different properties.  When I change a select option with those values, how would I assign the `foo` object to contain all the properties of the object, and not just the value.

From my example you'll see that I have it logging `foo`, but it is setting it to the value, not as properties of an object.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sc168nkn/1/)

HTML

```
<select name="objects" id="objects">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
var foo = {
  color: "red",
  height: 12
};

var bar = {
  color: "blue",
  height: 10
};

var baz = {
  color: "green",
  height: 5
};

$('#objects').on('change', function (e) {
    var foo = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Also, is there anyway to trigger this select event, if they select the option that's already selected? So if foo is selected, and they select foo again, trigger the change function.

Comment: what you trying to do?

Comment: @mmativ I want `foo` to inherif the properties of `bar` or `baz` when the appropriate option is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution to this is to create a parent wrapper object that should contain all of your objects, and access the object itself using **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**.

```
var objectsWrap=
{
 foo : {
  color: "red",
  height: 12
   },

 bar : {
  color: "blue",
  height: 10
   },

var baz : {
  color: "green",
  height: 5
   }
}

$('#objects').on('change', function (e) {
    var foo = objectsWrap[$(this).val()];
    console.log(foo);
});
```

After all the select value is a string and must be evaluated to object reference, and using eval **[is not recommended at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)**

**Update:**

to do a deep clone and ignore duplicates you can simply use **[for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** to iterate object keys, then do a simple check if object already **[has this property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)**, if yes ignore it, else assign as new property using **[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**

I hope the algorithm is clear, and doesn't require an example.

Comment: This solution works well, and makes a lot of sense for what I was looking for.  My only question is, what if `bar` and `baz` don't contain certain properties?  Is there a way to leave the current properties of `foo` and only override the ones that exist in `bar` and `baz`?

Comment: @DRBC yes ofcourse, check update, and let me know if you need a code snippet, usually I prefer explaining algorithm rather than writing typical snippets, it helps user to get to know more resources :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you for that. This makes perfect sense, thanks again.

Comment: @DRBC glad to help, please mark answer as correct if you find it helpful. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

> You should have object holding various elements than variable. Use `[]`(bracket) notation to get the `value` of a `key` as `key` is a variable.

Try this:

```js
var foo = {
  color: "red",
  height: 12
};

var bar = {
  color: "blue",
  height: 10
};

var baz = {
  color: "green",
  height: 5
};

var myObj = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: bar,
  baz: baz
};

$('#objects').on('change', function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  alert(JSON.stringify(myObj[val]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="objects" id="objects">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
```

**Or variable are `global`(keys of window), you can access it using `window[KEY]`**

Try this:

```js
var foo = {
  color: "red",
  height: 12
};

var bar = {
  color: "blue",
  height: 10
};

var baz = {
  color: "green",
  height: 5
};

$('#objects').on('change', function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  alert(JSON.stringify(window[val]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="objects" id="objects">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to approach like this.

```js
$('#objects').on('change', function (e) {
    var foo = $(this).val();
    var color = $(this).find(':selected').data('color')
    var height = $(this).find(':selected').data('height')
    console.log(color);
    console.log(height);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="objects" id="objects">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="foo" data-color="red" data-height="12">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar" data-color="blue" data-height="10">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz" data-color="green" data-height="5">Baz</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var definitions = {
   foo : {
      color: "red",
      height: 12
   },
   bar : {
      color: "blue",
      height: 10
   },
   baz : {
      color: "green",
      height: 5
   }
}

$('#objects').on('click', function (e) {
   var val = JSON.stringify(definitions[$(this).val()]);
   console.log(val);
});
```

> Note: changing the event from "change" to "click" fires it every time you
>   select something.